# CSS Menu's Submenu is not showing

Tags: php, css, wordpress, menu

Having a CSS issue with a menu on an old site that was recently worked on.
The issue is that the sub menu under the main menu is showing up as a very thin line with no option to actually select any of the ul li's.

There was no issue previously when the menu was hardcoded as HTML into the theme's header file but the client was not able to change the menu so in order to do things the right way I changed the HTML to:

```
<?php
wp_nav_menu( array( 
'theme_location' => 'header', 
'menu' => 'mobile-menu',
'menu_class' => 'max-menu',
'menu_id' => 'menu') ); 
?>
```

but now I am having the issue stated above. here is the URL for reference:
http://www.ellianaevents.com/

I tried changing the height and positioning of the sub-menu class but to no avail.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: _"There was no issue previously when the menu was hardcoded as HTML into the theme's header "_ - well then I suggest you start by comparing the HTML output of your now dynamic solution to the previous, hard-coded HTML ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `ul` have a `overflow-y:auto` so just change it with below css:

```
ul#menu {
   overflow: visible;
}
```

Comment: Thank everyone for the help. Minal's suggestion fixed it but I think in general people here on stackoverflow should try to help others without constantly downvoting them, as a backend dev moving into front end it's not always easy.

Answer (score 1):

add this add this `enter code here`ul.max-menu {
    overflow-y: visible;
}

line-number : 154

Answer (score 0):

```
We have to add submenu css in style.css file to display submenu options in the menu 

after displaying menu using function below

wp_nav_menu(array('menu_name'=>'Name of menu given in backend','container'=>false,'menu_class'=>'class of menu if you want to give if you dont want then leave it blank'));
```